# Find all possible configurations of a finite dipole system

Tags: combinatorics

I have a system which is composed of the following blocks

$$[-,+],[+,+],[+,-],[-,-]$$

I can compose a system of $n$ blocks with the only rule that the edges act as a dipole.

for example
$$[-,+][-,+][-,-][+,-]$$

is a possible configuration of $n=4$.

Is it possible to create a code with mathematica that will produce all the possible configurations for any given $n$?

Comment: `With[{n = 2}, Tuples[{-1, +1}, n]]` ?

Comment: this gives all the possible elements, but how can I compose all the possible combinations for any given $n$, which will perserve a dipole between the elements?

Comment: "the only rule that the edges act as a dipole." - to clarify, an admissible configuration is one with + or - on both ends, and +/- always being adjacent between the two poles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AttachDipole[x : {___, {_, "+"}}] := Append[x, #] & /@ {{"-", "-"}, {"-", "+"}};
AttachDipole[x : {___, {_, "-"}}] := Append[x, #] & /@ {{"+", "-"}, {"+", "+"}};


AttachDipoles[dipls_List] := Join @@ AttachDipole /@ dipls
AllDipoles[n_] := 
   Nest[AttachDipoles, {{{"-", "-"}}, {{"-", "+"}}, {{"+", "-"}}, {{"+", "+"}}}, n - 1]

AllDipoles[1]
```

> ```
> {{{"-", "-"}}, {{"-", "+"}}, {{"+", "-"}}, {{"+", "+"}}}
> ```

```
AllDipoles[2]
```

> ```
> {{{"-", "-"}, {"+", "-"}}, {{"-", "-"}, {"+", "+"}}, 
>  {{"-", "+"}, {"-", "-"}}, {{"-", "+"}, {"-", "+"}}, 
>  {{"+", "-"}, {"+", "-"}}, {{"+", "-"}, {"+", "+"}}, 
>  {{"+", "+"}, {"-", "-"}}, {{"+", "+"}, {"-", "+"}}}
> ```

```
AllDipoles[3]
```

> ```
> {{{"-", "-"}, {"+", "-"}, {"+", "-"}}, {{"-", "-"}, {"+", "-"}, {"+", "+"}}, 
>  {{"-", "-"}, {"+", "+"}, {"-", "-"}}, {{"-", "-"}, {"+", "+"}, {"-", "+"}}, 
>  {{"-", "+"}, {"-", "-"}, {"+", "-"}}, {{"-", "+"}, {"-", "-"}, {"+", "+"}}, 
>  {{"-", "+"}, {"-", "+"}, {"-", "-"}}, {{"-", "+"}, {"-", "+"}, {"-", "+"}}, 
>  {{"+", "-"}, {"+", "-"}, {"+", "-"}}, {{"+", "-"}, {"+", "-"}, {"+", "+"}}, 
>  {{"+", "-"}, {"+", "+"}, {"-", "-"}}, {{"+", "-"}, {"+", "+"}, {"-", "+"}}, 
>  {{"+", "+"}, {"-", "-"}, {"+", "-"}}, {{"+", "+"}, {"-", "-"}, {"+", "+"}}, 
>  {{"+", "+"}, {"-", "+"}, {"-", "-"}}, {{"+", "+"}, {"-", "+"}, {"-", "+"}}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one liner:

```
n = 3;
DeleteCases[Tuples[Tuples[{-1, 1}, 2],  n], {___, {_, x_}, {y_, _}, ___} /; ( x == y)]

{{{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, -1}}, {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 
   1}}, {{-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, -1}}, {{-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 
   1}}, {{-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}}, {{-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, 
   1}}, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}}, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 
   1}}, {{1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, -1}}, {{1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 
   1}}, {{1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, -1}}, {{1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {{1, 
   1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}}, {{1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {-1, 
   1}, {-1, -1}}, {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}}
```

Comment: You can make the pattern a bit more compact with `{___, {_, x_}, {x_, _}, ___}`